# Morris.js - Is There any Setter Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I there any setter function for [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)? I've been through their documentation and it seems there is only one example of changing values of the data points using [`setData()`](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html).

But when you change data you might need to change labels on the x/y axis or change other options too. So, **is there any general setter method on morris.js?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspecting the [script](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/morris.js) and `setData()` function I've found there isn't any setter function. But options can be reset and redraw like below.

### Initiate the Chart on js file (Hard Coded)

```
var options = {
            element : 'lead-summery',
            data : xChart.leads,
            xkey: 'date',
            ykeys: ['total', 'bananas', 'apples', 'oranges'],
            labels:['Total', 'Bananas', 'Apples', 'Oranges'],
            lineColors:['#E67A77', '#D9DD81', '#79D1CF'],
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            lineWidth: 1
        };

        // you must save the cart in a global variable
        window.myAreaChart = Morris.Area(options);
```

### Dynamically Update The Chart Options

Now say we want to Add some new data via AJAX and want to change `xLabelFormat` function and `xLabelAngle` for labels.

```
var data = {}; // we get this from ajax call or whatever

// now we update the options

// xLabelFormat callback function
window.myAreaChart.options.xLabelFormat = function(date){
    return formatDate(date);
}

// xLabelAngle
window.myAreaChart.xLabelAngle = 60;

// add data and update the chart
window.myAreaChart.setData(data);
```

**It is very important to understand** that in order to update the chart we need to call `redraw()` method for example `window.myAreaChart.redraw()`. Otherwise the chart won't update. We did not call `redraw()` on the example above because the `setData()` method calls it so no need for call it twice. But if you do not use `setData()` you will need to call `redraw()` in order to update the chart visually.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi Yep, aware of that. In Indonesian correct?

Comment: window.myAreaChart.setData(data); should have the "data" as a JSON object, not simply a string. Can use JSON.parse(data) to convert a string into a JSON object for use with setData();